# Allow user to only input text?

Tags: c#

how do I make a boolean statement to only allow text? I have this code for only allowing the user to input numbers but ca'nt figure out how to do text.

```
 bool Dest = double.TryParse(this.xTripDestinationTextBox.Text, out Miles);
 bool MilesGal = double.TryParse(this.xTripMpgTextBox.Text, out Mpg);
 bool PriceGal = double.TryParse(this.xTripPricepgTextBox.Text, out Price);
```

Comment: What do you mean by “text”? Letters of the alphabet only?

Comment: Yes it's to force a user to only be able to enter his first and last name only

Comment: What if the names contains spaces, hyphens or other special characters? Maybe even some people have digits in their names, who knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code in the KeyPress event:

```
if (!char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar)) {
e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: This one worked the best for my solution but thanks for all the answers guys I appreciate it alot.

Comment: @Michael, did you look at the MaskedTextBox?

Answer (score 4):

Update: looking at your comment I would advise you to read this article:

[User Input Validation in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx)

---

Original answer: The simplest way, at least if you are using .NET 3.5, is to use LINQ:

```
bool isAllLetters = s.All(c => char.IsLetter(c));
```

In older .NET versions you can create a method to do this for you:

```
bool isAllLetters(string s)
{
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetter(c))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can also use a regular expression. If you want to allow any letter as defined in Unicode then you can use this regular expression:

```
bool isOnlyLetters = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\p{L}+$");
```

If you want to restrict to A-Z then you can use this:

```
bool isOnlyLetters = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression, browse here: http://regexlib.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of a few things.

1. User Regular Expression to check that the string matches your concept of 'Text' only
2. Write some code that checks each character against a list of valid characters. Or even use `char.IsLetter()`
3. Use the MaskedTextBox and set a custom mask to limit input to text only characters

Answer (score 0):

I found hooking up into the text changed event of a textbox and accepting/rejecting the changes an acceptable solution. To "only allow text" is a rather vague definition, but you may as well check if your newly added text (the next char) is a number or not and simply reject all numbers/disallowed characters. This will make users feel they can only enter characters and special characters (like dots, question marks etc.).

```
private void UTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string lastCharacter = this.Text[this.Text.Length-1].ToString();
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(lastCharacter, "[0-9]", RegexOptions.None);
    if (matches.Count > 0) //character is a number, reject it.
    {
         this.Text = Text.Substring(0, Text.Length-1);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Only checking the last character does not help if a non-conforming character is inserted in the middle of the string. It might be better to validate the entire string on each TextChanged event.